# Get the last auto increment id

Tags: php, sql, pdo, auto-increment

lets say my code is:

```
$req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO test(name, surname) VALUES(:name, :surname)');
$req->execute(array(
    'name' => $name,
    'surname' => $surname));
```

And my table `test` has an auto increment field named `id`

What is the best way to get the 'id' corresponding to `$req`?

Comment: Are you using MYSQLI or PDO? I would guess PDO, but I want to make sure.

Comment: yes, i'm using PDO @MisterMelancholy

Comment: Use the lastInsertId of PDO http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Comment: @Arthur Please be careful when editing code in languages you don't know! `->` and `=>` are atomic operators in PHP. The whitespace you've been trying to add in edits you've been suggesting would BREAK the code...yet they keep getting almost approved by sleepwalking reviewers. Also, please look for posts that actually have things that need *fixing*. These kinds of edits really wouldn't be helpful even if they didn't break the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PDO has a method for this:

```
$id = $pdo->lastInsertId();
```

or in your case:

```
$id = $bdd->lastInsertId();
```

You can find more information about the lastInsertID method [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php).

Comment: So I was wondering, what would happen if multiple DB transactions happened at the same time (multiple users on different computers), would it be possible for the `lastInsertId()` function to return the wrong id???

Comment: @James111 I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. `$pdo->lastInsertId()` will return the most recent insert ID of object `$pdo`.